Scale SQS processing with a ECS task
I am trying to consume a SQS queue in a ECS task. The SQS is receiving messages at a rate of 600 - 1000 messages per minute but ECS consumer can only process 10 messages in a single batch. If i try to process the messages in async mode it with either run out of memory or the mongo DB cursor will reach its limit (The message is processed and loaded into Document DB).
Is there any efficient way to scale this process?

Do all the messages in the SQS queue have the same group ID? Or are there multiple group IDs in the messages? In other words, do all the messages in the queue absolutely have to be processed in the same order they were added to the queue, or can one server be processing messages from message producer A, while another is processing messages from message producer B?

They have multiple group ID and there are 5 tasks processing them. With that as-well i can achieve a maximum of 50 messages per minute. Also the processing in the same order is not necessary.

You can have as many tasks processing them as you have group IDs. That's how you scale the processing out. If the order doesn't matter at all, then switching to a regular queue instead of a FIFO queue, would allow you to have as many tasks processing the messages as you wanted, with no limitation.
